# custom components in custom authentication objects

Tags: cakephp

How to use components (custom or base like `Session`) in custom authentication objects? (which located in `Controller/Components/Auth`)??

I tried `public $components = array('Session', 'name of my custom component');` but it doesn't work.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Since I was looking for a way to do this myself and I found this question being asked, I'll share my findings.

I took a look at BaseAuthenticate::__construct() and it seems like AuthComponent sends the controller's ComponentCollection to each Autehntication object. I tried doing

```
$this->Session = $this->_Collection->__get('Session');
$this->Session->write('foo', 'bar');
```

and it worked but only because I am already loading the SessionComponent in my AppController. ComponentCollection::__get() only returned loaded components. You might want to look at the ComponentCollection class and its parent, ObjectCollection for more details on how to play with the components.

This is what I did in my Authentication class:

```
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param ComponentCollection $collection The Component collection used on this request.
 * @param array $settings Array of settings to use.
 */
public function __construct(ComponentCollection $collection, $settings) {
    $settings = array_merge($this->settings, $settings);
    parent::__construct($collection, $settings);
    $this->http = new HttpSocket();
    $this->_initComponentCollection();
}

/**
 * Initializes all the loaded Components for the Authentication Object.
 * Attaches a reference of each component to the Authentication Object.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function _initComponentCollection() {
    $components = $this->_Collection->loaded();
    if (!empty($components)) {
        foreach ($components as $name) {
            $this->{$name} = $this->_Collection->__get($name);
        }
    }
}
```

This makes use of only the loaded components since I do not want to load all the components. I'll be opening up a ticket with cakephp to see if it is viable to add a similar snippet to the BaseAuthenticate class.

Answer (score -1):

As per the CakeBook:

```
// Pass settings in $components array
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'name of custom authentication object'
        )
    )
);
```

The authenticate property of the Auth component is where you state the authentication object you will use, whether it be form, basic, digest, or a custom one.

Comment: This does not answer the question. You are stating how to load a custom authentication object. What the OP is asking is how to use components inside the custom Authentication Object.